# How to store Google Firestore data in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Im downloading data from Google Firestore and I'm wondering whats the best approach to make the data accessible throughout the app's run time without downloading it again?

Is it better store it in a struct or in a Swift file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you won't be mutating the data and will be deserializing then I would suggest keeping it in a class. If the data is small then maybe even store in user defaults. Another choice would be to use Core Data.